# ifconfig showing eth0 when using wifi

Tags: ubuntu

I'm using Ubuntu on VM. When running the ifconfig, I get back two blocks; one for eth0 and one for lo. However, it is my understanding that eth0 is only for when you are connected to the internet via an ethernet cable, and yet I am using wifi and do not have a wlan0 block.

Also i get same IP address on eth0 even when connection made with different wifi network.

Can someone please explain why this happening?

i am trying to connect sensor over MQTT broker which is runing on ubuntu but problem with IP address. where in window CMD line IP changes whene wifi connection change but not in ubuntu why ?

Answer (score 0):

With the default setup of most Virtual Machine systems you can not directly connect to the virtual machine from outside the host machine, they run on their own closed network which is NAT proxied to the hosts network.

To expose a service running on a virtual machine you will need to setup some form of port forwarding.